# 'Termination due to memory pressure" in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have started receiving app termination due to memory pressures very recently (mostly with iOS 7). The app used to work very well on iOS 6.

The app is mostly uses a UIWebView to display a webpage. However for a few webpages it creates ever increasing **Dirty memory** with most of it due to Image IO and Performance tool data (see attached instruments screenshots). I am completely clueless as to where to dig next. Could someone guide me what should I do here onwards? In the second screenshot I see a sudden bump in the memory allocations. Is there a way to spot the process/part of the code which caused it?

**EDIT** One can reproduce these results in a simple demo kept at www.github.com/nikhiljjoshi/iosCrash (just change the site to www.nzz.ch).

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

[image: screenshot with increasing dirty memory]
[image: Is there a way to spot the process/line in the code which causes this bump?]

Comment: In future I recommand to make a screenshot with cmd+shift+4 like this it is more anonymous.

Comment: Thanks... I did realize it after posting, but did not act fast :(... now edited!

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Do you solve this issue ?